# spring security url authorization not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a question about url authorization in my application. If I do not log into my application and go to home.htm I get redirected to login.htm. That's excellent and exactly what I wanted.

But I've just finished creating a service interface into my application that returns JSON strings. An example url for this is...

```
http://localhost/myapp/service/repManHealth/applicationHealthMessage.json
```

To my surprise this url is working without a user authenticating. In my applicationContext I have all the security mapping settings. For example....

```
<http pattern="/login.htm" security="none"/>
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
   <intercept-url pattern="/home.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

I didn't add "/service/repManHealth/applicationHealthMessage.json" into these mappings so then why is a user allowed to hit those url's without authenitcation.

Is the default behavior that if a url does not match an intercept-url pattern specified then it does not get secured?

thanks

Comment: Only the `/home.htm` URL is secured everything else is open to anyone.  As you already stated if a URL doesn't match an intercept-url pattern is isn't secured.

Comment: Ok. So default behaviour is not to secure? Are you sure? Because my spring security filter in my web.xml is specified as /* . And also if default behaviour is not to secure what is the point of using security=none of certain urls?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. If you want to have security applied you will have to add intercept-url with `/**` as a pattern to catch all. Security `none` will apply no spring security filters whereas a missing pattern would lead to applying some of the spring security filters (leaving out the one that actually applies the security as that doesn't match any URL pattern).